# DataGridView Does not refresh after editing in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a data grid view whose data source gets assigned a list of items after the following function on load:

```
public void refreshGrid(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    dgvItems.SuspendLayout();
    itemBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
    List<Item> items = db.Items.ToList();  // db is MyContext db = new MyContext();
    itemBindingSource.DataSource = items;
    dgvItems.DataSource = null;
    dgvItems.DataSource = itemBindingSource;
    itemBindingSource.ResumeBinding();
    dgvItems.ResumeLayout();
}

private void AllItemsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   refreshGrid();
}
```

and there is a edit button which does the following on click:

```
private void btnEditItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Item item = (Item)dgvItems.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    var editForm = new EditItemForm(item);
    editForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(refreshGrid);
    editForm.Show();
}
```

i.e. opens an edit form and assigns `refreshGrid()` to its closing event.

On that Edit Form I have this `Save` button which does this:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Item itemEdited = db.Items.Where(i => i.itemId == itemEditing.itemId).Single();
        itemEdited.categoryId = (int)cbxCategory.SelectedValue;
        itemEdited.description = tbxDescription.Text;
        itemEdited.price = (Double)nudPrice.Value;
        db.Entry(itemEdited).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        this.Close();
    }
```

the item edit is working, but is apparent only after closing and reopening the edit form, i.e. that `refreshGrid()` method which was assigned to its closing event is not working!

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not working or it's not called? What wrong behaviour do you experience? An exception? Wrong data?

Comment: @PaoloCosta, I am thinking it is not called because the same method is working for my `AddForm`. Or, the problem is with EntityFramework Context class. Maybe it is saving after refresh method is called. No exception, no wrong data. Everything is working fine except that datagrid view is not updated unless it is closed and reopened

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake. The mistake was  using two different instances of Context class.

The solution was to add:

```
SomsaContext database = new SomsaContext();  // i.e. new instance of Context class
```

right before the refresh takes place.